# How to Find from which folder my PC is taking regular backup via rsnapshot

Tags: 12.04, rsnapshot

We are taking daily incremental backup from our main office in New Jersy.For that we are using rsnapshot & we have generated authentication key so that we don't need any daily password authentication. Now My question is How can I know from which folder it is taking daily backup to my PC.

P.S : I am using ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit

Please give me direct & simple answer because I am new for Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Only you can answer this as when you configured rsnapshot you should have specified the directories/folders that you wanted to back up and where you wanted them placed onto your computer.

Perhaps you have not really understood the way rsnapshot works?

Here is an (simple) example config that may help:

```
backup  remoteuser@newjerseyserver:/etc/ newjersey/
```

The above config is backing up the /etc directory on the remote server newjersey to your local computer's rsnapshot_root defined area in a directory named newjersey.
You would have specified the rsnapshot_root area in your /etc/rsnapshot.conf file - as an example if it was set to /rsnapshots/ then the newjersey etc directory would be seen on your local computer in /rsnapshots/hourly.0/newjersey/etc based on you using an hourly rsnapshot.

If the above is making no sense at all, then google for "rsnapshot tutorial" and read the many sites with articles on rnsapshot with screenshots etc... it will make things clearer.